# The type or namespace name 'Helper' does not exist in the namespace 'Google.Apis.Samples

Tags: c#

I have added namespace `using Google.Apis.Samples.Helper;` but after running code I am getting below error which dll I have to add?

> > The type or namespace name 'Helper' does not exist in the namespace 'Google.Apis.Samples

Comment: do you have to add an assembly reference?

Comment: Have you added the assembly reference?

Comment: which reference i have to add for this

Comment: google-api-dotnet-client  downloaded this but which dll i have to add

Comment: Added --Google.Apis,Google.Apis.Task.v1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a google developer, but it seems your assembly is downloadable here [at google](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/source/browse/Tools/Lib/Google.Apis.Samples.Helper.dll?r=ba22a0c3def9e76c5b2d727abad351bbed7f3002)

Comment: dll is called, quite logically, Google.Apis.Samples.Helper.dll

Comment: Google.Apis.Samples.Helper.dll i have google this dll but i am not geeting this dll to dowload

Comment: on the link I posted, click on "view raw file", on the right under "File info". Weird name, I agree, but it'll download fine...

Comment: where is the link you posted

Comment: I'll make it even easier for you: http://google-api-dotnet-client.googlecode.com/hg-history/ba22a0c3def9e76c5b2d727abad351bbed7f3002/Tools/Lib/Google.Apis.Samples.Helper.dll

You may have to copy paste it to your adress bar

Comment: one more help HoneyBadger  can you please tell me what i do  pls  look at the link-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13248340/retrieve-the-user-credential-of-google-drive-login

Comment: like I said, im not a google developer, but ill have a look after the weekend.
You say you get errors, what are the errors?

Also, if you like my answer, you can accept it as answer....

Comment: error while i am running the code - namespace name UserInfo could not be found